# janusGraphManagement.getOrCreatePropertyKey() Causing Could not read messages for timestamp

Tags: gremlin, traversal, cassandra-3.0, docker-container, janusgraph

## Problem

Why is an empty JanusGraph not able to `read messages for timestamp`?
What message is JanusGraph referring for `janusGraphManagement.getOrCreatePropertyKey()`?
How is this warning fixed and why does it produce so many when data is added?

```bash
[WARN] [o.j.d.l.k.KCVSLog.pool-5-thread-1] ::    Could not read messages for timestamp [2023-05-17T12:50:45.282434100Z] (this read will be retried)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Timestamp overflow detected: 2023-05-17T12:50:45.282434100Z
```

```java
        logger.info("g.V().count().next():\t" + g.V().count().next());
        PropertyKey propertyKey = janusGraphManagement.getOrCreatePropertyKey("_id");
```

## Reproduction

### Steps

1. Create-and-Startup a [Cassandra [Docker container]](https://hub.docker.com/_/cassandra)

   ```bash
   docker run --name jg-cassandra -d -e CASSANDRA_START_RPC=true -p 9160:9160 -p 9042:9042 -p 7199:7199 -p 7001:7001 -p 7000:7000 cassandra:3.11
   ```
2. Load a large (or at least non-trival) dataset into JanusGraph

   1. A sample "medium-sized" dataset is [ICIJ Offshore Dataleaks](https://github.com/ICIJ/offshoreleaks-data-packages/blob/eabbabfeaf1983c2b83c11125802fcdeda92d9ac/data/icij-offshoreleaks-44.dump)
   2. Medium meaning a larger dataset than someone could hard-code distinct and "random" data
3. Create-and-Run this Java + Maven Project (code below)
4. Results

   1. Expected: JanusGraph-Cassandra to handle reading the messages
   2. Actually: JanusGraph-Cassandra will throw the message regardless of setup when these 2-lines exist

      ```json
      [WARN] [o.j.d.l.k.KCVSLog.pool-5-thread-1] ::    Could not read messages for timestamp [2023-05-17T12:50:45.282434100Z] (this read will be retried)
      java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Timestamp overflow detected: 2023-05-17T12:50:45.282434100Z
      ```

### Tried

1. Adding data to see if it was a null or zero-length issue
   This just made the error repeat more and wait to complete longer
   Issue permanently persists for `g.V()` now
2. Creating a new Docker-container
   Issue still persisted
3. Using a different `g.V()` execution `g.V.drop().iterate()`
   Issue still responded the same
4. Changing the sequence of when `getOrCreatePropertyKey()` happens to when `g.V()` happens
   Issue still happens when `getOrCreatePropertyKey()` is called
5. Commenting out `getOrCreatePropertyKey()` and leaving `g.V().count().next()`
   Issue goes away
6. Commenting out `g.V().count().next()` and leaving `getOrCreatePropertyKey()`
   Issue goes away
7. Commenting 1 of each `getOrCreatePropertyKey()` and `g.V()` back-in
   Issue comes back
8. Changing how timestamps were handled `set(TIMESTAMP_PROVIDER.toStringWithoutRoot(), "NANO")`
   Issue does not change
9. Switched to Java-11 [corretto-11 11.0.19]
   Issue still persists

### Logs

```json
2023-05-17 07:50:43,822 [INFO] [c.d.o.d.i.c.ContactPoints.main] ::   Contact point localhost:29042 resolves to multiple addresses, will use them all ([localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1])
2023-05-17 07:50:43,930 [INFO] [c.d.o.d.i.c.DefaultMavenCoordinates.main] ::     DataStax Java driver for Apache Cassandra(R) (com.datastax.oss:java-driver-core) version 4.15.0
2023-05-17 07:50:44,444 [INFO] [c.d.o.d.i.c.t.Clock.JanusGraph Session-admin-0] ::   Using native clock for microsecond precision
2023-05-17 07:50:44,725 [WARN] [c.d.o.d.i.c.l.h.OptionalLocalDcHelper.JanusGraph Session-admin-0] ::     [JanusGraph Session|default] You specified datacenter1 as the local DC, but some contact points are from a different DC: Node(endPoint=localhost/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:29042, hostId=null, hashCode=5aad4393)=null; please provide the correct local DC, or check your contact points
2023-05-17 07:50:44,987 [INFO] [o.j.g.i.UniqueInstanceIdRetriever.main] ::   Generated unique-instance-id=c0a8564916248-rmt-lap-win201
2023-05-17 07:50:45,011 [INFO] [c.d.o.d.i.c.ContactPoints.main] ::   Contact point localhost:29042 resolves to multiple addresses, will use them all ([localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1])
2023-05-17 07:50:45,045 [INFO] [c.d.o.d.i.c.t.Clock.JanusGraph Session-admin-0] ::   Using native clock for microsecond precision
2023-05-17 07:50:45,086 [WARN] [c.d.o.d.i.c.l.h.OptionalLocalDcHelper.JanusGraph Session-admin-0] ::     [JanusGraph Session|default] You specified datacenter1 as the local DC, but some contact points are from a different DC: Node(endPoint=localhost/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:29042, hostId=null, hashCode=83832b8)=null; please provide the correct local DC, or check your contact points
2023-05-17 07:50:45,112 [INFO] [o.j.d.c.ExecutorServiceBuilder.main] ::  Initiated fixed thread pool of size 40
2023-05-17 07:50:45,254 [INFO] [o.j.g.d.StandardJanusGraph.main] ::  Gremlin script evaluation is disabled
2023-05-17 07:50:45,282 [INFO] [o.j.d.l.k.KCVSLog.main] ::   Loaded unidentified ReadMarker start time 2023-05-17T12:50:45.282434100Z into org.janusgraph.diskstorage.log.kcvs.KCVSLog$MessagePuller@48b4a043
2023-05-17 07:50:45,346 [WARN] [o.j.g.t.StandardJanusGraphTx.main] ::    Query requires iterating over all vertices [[]]. For better performance, use indexes
2023-05-17 07:50:45,359 [INFO] [Main.main] ::    g.V().count().next():  0
2023-05-17 07:50:45,393 [WARN] [o.j.d.l.k.KCVSLog.pool-5-thread-1] ::    Could not read messages for timestamp [2023-05-17T12:50:45.282434100Z] (this read will be retried)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Timestamp overflow detected: 2023-05-17T12:50:45.282434100Z
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.log.kcvs.KCVSLog.getTimeSlice(KCVSLog.java:393) ~[janusgraph-core-1.0.0-20230504-014643.988c094.jar:?]
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.log.kcvs.KCVSLog.access$1500(KCVSLog.java:115) ~[janusgraph-core-1.0.0-20230504-014643.988c094.jar:?]
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.log.kcvs.KCVSLog$MessagePuller.run(KCVSLog.java:743) [janusgraph-core-1.0.0-20230504-014643.988c094.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) [?:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) [?:?]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

### Code

```java
public class Test {
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Main.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        JanusGraph janusGraph = JanusGraphFactory.build()
                .set("storage.backend", "cql")
                .set("storage.hostname", "localhost:29042")
//                .set(TIMESTAMP_PROVIDER.toStringWithoutRoot(), "NANO")
                .open();
        JanusGraphManagement janusGraphManagement = janusGraph.openManagement();
        GraphTraversalSource g = janusGraph.traversal();
        logger.info("g.V().count().next():\t" + g.V().count().next());
//        g.V().limit(10000).drop().iterate();
        PropertyKey propertyKey = janusGraphManagement.getOrCreatePropertyKey("_id");
//        GraphTraversalSource g = janusGraph.traversal();
//        logger.info("g.V().count().next():\t" + g.V().count().next());
        janusGraph.close();
    }
```

### Resources

1. [Maven 3.8.1](https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi)
2. [Java 11.0.19 (corretto-11)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/corretto/latest/corretto-11-ug/downloads-list.html)
3. [JanusGraph 1.0.0-20230504-014643.988c094](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/releases/tag/v1.0.0-rc2)
4. [Windows 10](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10%20)
5. [Docker](https://hub.docker.com/_/cassandra)
6. [Cassandra:latest [container]](https://docs.janusgraph.org/storage-backend/cassandra/)
7. [Harvard's Lung Cancer Dataset](https://dataverse.harvard.edu/dataset.xhtml?persistentId=doi:10.7910/DVN/RIXLG8)

Comment: You mention that you're on Java 17. JanusGraph is unfortunately only compatible with Java 11 and 8 right now. Can you please try whether using Java 11 already fixes this problem?

Comment: Switched the Maven-Compiler-Target and Java-Runtime to 11, issue still persists.